# Will I lose my progress when I create a Minecraft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft without an account, but figured it'd be useful when I start playing multiplayer.
I only have singleplayer survival worlds: will they be affected if I make an account?

Comment: What do you mean with "without an account"? Demo mode? Then it's a good question, I've never tried that. Or do you mean cracked launchers and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not be affected. Survival worlds are stored locally (on your computer) in the `saves` folder. When you create an account, your worlds will not be affected by this.

Just in case, you can always  create back-ups of the worlds in question. To do this, please see [this article](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2961769-backing-up-minecraft-worlds).